# How to fix 'address of stack memory associated with local variable' when returning a variable address from function?

Tags: c++, pointers

My professor had me copy and paste the code below she wrote, and it kept on giving me bugs.

By running her program, the output was 1 for any value.

Logically, I understand how the function should return the address and in the main it prints the value of it. Theoretically, that is.

So here's what I tried so far:

1. Simply removing the statement p = cube(&n) and replacing with:

   ```
   std::cout << "Cube of " << n << " is " << cube(&n) << std::endl;
   ```

   This worked.
2. In order to solve the "local variable" error, I made 'result' a global variable.
3. In cube(), I did:

   ```
   int *cube(int *number) {
       int result = (*number) * (*number) * (*number);
       int *newResult = &newResult;
       return newResult;
   }
   ```

   ...but it outputted 1 for any integer.

This is the code sample she shared.

```
#include <iostream>

int *cube(int *);

int main() {
    int n, *p;
    std::cout << "Enter an int: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    p = cube(&n);

    std::cout << "Cube of " << n << " is " << *p << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

int *cube(int *number) {
    int result = (*number) * (*number) * (*number);
    return &result;
}
```

According to her, the output of this program should be the cube of the inputted integer. For example, 3 in -> 27 out.

Comment: There is no reason to use pointers here. If you do want to return a pointer, either use address of existing variable or create `new int`, set its value, work with it, and then `delete` it.

Comment: Her code returns a pointer to a part of the stack that becomes undefined once you return from the function.  Like @dyukha says if you want to return a pointer from this function it should be to something on the heap (created using new()) not the stack.

Comment: This looks like a mega duplicate. What is the canonical question for returning references/pointers from a function to things on the stack? It must have been asked in 2008. Some leads: *[Returning pointer from a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7754986/)* (C, 2011) and *[Using C-string gives Warning: "Address of stack memory associated with local variable returned"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18041100/)* (2013)

Comment: Related (but none of the answers deal with this problem): *[What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/)*

Comment: Tagged with both C and C++... - *[Return pointer to data declared in function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320551/return-pointer-to-data-declared-in-function)*

Comment: This is used a duplicate target for C++ questions: *[C++ Returning reference to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable)* (2011, five answers and 137 upvotes).

Comment: Even higher scored (the same fundamental problem): *[Returning an array using C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11656532/)* (2012, 12 answers, and 196 upvotes)

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to return a [local reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4643713/c-returning-reference-to-local-variable) that cannot be accessed outside of it declaration scope. You need to allocate memory on the heap using the `new` keyword and not the stack. Check out the difference [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57483/what-are-the-differences-between-a-pointer-variable-and-a-reference-variable-in/57492#57492).

```
int* cube(int number) {
    return new int (number * number * number);
}
```

Note that I pass `number` by value and not by reference as there is no obvious speed performance/need to modify the value of the passed in variable. I also do not bother making an intermediate variable, `newResult`, as the result of new can just be returned. Do keep in mind that if I were to create an intermediate value `newResult`, it would be of type `int*`. Do NOT forget to give back the memory when you no longer need the result. Use the `delete` keyword to deallocate the memory.
All of that being said, do not bother returning a pointer as use of heap is slow and manual memory allocation is messy.

Below is what you should use.

```
int cube(int number) {
    return number * number * number;
}
```

Creating a static and global variables should be used with care as they will use more memory.

Passing a primitive variable by reference is also not advisable read [Reasons to not pass simple types by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10770410/reasons-to-not-pass-simple-types-by-reference).

```
void cube3(int &number) {
   number = (number) * (number) * (number);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is about a scope of variables.

**1. Global variable.**

The 'result' is a local variable that can not be accessed or used outside { and } block. You can use it by a global variable.

The global variables are declared at the top of the program outside all of the functions or blocks.

```
static int result;
void cube(int *number) {
    result = (*number) * (*number) * (*number);
}
```

In C, you can pass parameters to a function by pointers.

```
void cube2(int *number) {
    *number = (*number) * (*number) * (*number);
}
```

**2. Pass by reference.**

In C++, you can pass parameters to a function either by pointers(cube2) or by reference code blow:

```
void cube3(int &number) {
   number = (number) * (number) * (number);
}
```

In a main function:

```
int main() {
    int input_num, n;
    std::cout << "Enter an int: ";
    std::cin >> n;

    input_num = n;
    cube(&n);

    std::cout << "Cube of " << input_num << " is " << result << std::endl;

    cube2(&n);
    std::cout << "Cube of " << input_num << " is " << n << std::endl;

    n = input_num;
    cube3(n);
    std::cout << "Cube of " << input_num << " is " << n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

`result` is a local variable and allocated on the stack. When that function ends that memory owned by result is no longer valid. Therefore any pointer to that memory is not valid.

For a function that simple there's no need to bother with pointers. Just return a copy of the result by value.

```
int cube(int *number)
{
    int result = (*number) * (*number) * (*number);
    return result;
}
```